# How to add href in Angular2?

Tags: angular

Here is a template:

```
<h2 (click)="goToPost()">{{post.title}}</h2>
```

goToPost() function:

```
goToPost() {
    this.router.navigate(['/post', this.post.id]);
}
```

And the resulting link is: mysite.dev/post/13

But now I can't copy link by right-click. How should I implement anchor tag here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a [routerLink]="['/post', this.post.id]">{{post.title}}</a>
```